# Передача значения в глобальную переменную javascript

Tags: javascript, nw.js

Использую nw.js + nedb.
Как вывести значение docs в глобальную переменную resultVal. Сейчас resulVal ничего не выводит.

```
var Datastore = require('nedb');
var db = new Datastore({filename : 'users'});
db.loadDatabase();

var resultVal = "";
db.find({}, function (err, docs){
    console.log (docs);
    resultVal = docs;
});
console.log (resultVal);
```

Comment: Возможный дубликат вопроса: [Как вернуть значение из события или из функции обратного вызова? Или хотя бы дождаться их окончания](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/554290/%d0%9a%d0%b0%d0%ba-%d0%b2%d0%b5%d1%80%d0%bd%d1%83%d1%82%d1%8c-%d0%b7%d0%bd%d0%b0%d1%87%d0%b5%d0%bd%d0%b8%d0%b5-%d0%b8%d0%b7-%d1%81%d0%be%d0%b1%d1%8b%d1%82%d0%b8%d1%8f-%d0%b8%d0%bb%d0%b8-%d0%b8%d0%b7-%d1%84%d1%83%d0%bd%d0%ba%d1%86%d0%b8%d0%b8-%d0%be%d0%b1%d1%80%d0%b0%d1%82%d0%bd%d0%be%d0%b3%d0%be-%d0%b2%d1%8b%d0%b7%d0%be%d0%b2%d0%b0-%d0%98%d0%bb%d0%b8-%d1%85%d0%be%d1%82%d1%8f-%d0%b1%d1%8b-%d0%b4%d0%be%d0%b6)

Comment: Вы просто вывели переменную в консоль до того как присвоили ей значение

Answer (score 0):

Функция,

```js
function (err, docs){
    console.log (docs);
    resultVal = docs;
}
```

которая передается вторым параметром в метод `find`это callback (или другими словами «функция обратного вызова»). Они широко используются в JavaScript, например, в асинхронном коде, в обработчиках событий, в методах setTimeout и setInterval.

Но, если сделать вот так, то выведет:

```js
var Datastore = require('nedb');
var db = new Datastore({filename : 'users'});
db.loadDatabase();

var resultVal = "";
db.find({}, function (err, docs){
    console.log (docs);
    resultVal = docs;

    console.log (resultVal);
});
```